# iframe inside a div. scrolling the div not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

I know that trying to scroll the iframe itself in not the way to go and instead i should be scrolling the div.  Thing is it doesn't work.  What is wrong with this code?  Is it a google thing?  I'm using the custom search so it shows up in the frame but I know google and frames don't like to play with each other.

HTML

```
<div id="googleframe"><iframe id="googleseo" src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=hey+there&btnG=Search"></iframe></div>
```

JS

```
var seoFrame = document.getElementById('googleseo');
seoFrame.src = googleSearch;
seoFrame.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('googleframe').scrollTop = 300;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it does not work because of the same domain policy. There are workarounds [described in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript#comment6499395_1229879).

Answer (score 1):

It was a CSS issue. The iframe wasn't long enough to scroll.  It was the same height as my div so I made it longer and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the scrollTop referencing the iframe, not the body within the frame. The iframe itself doesn't have a scrollbar, it's the document within it.

Fiddle of it working http://jsfiddle.net/ebzxzgmo/

```
var seoFrame = document.getElementById('googleseo');
var elem = (seoFrame.contentDocument||seoFrame.contentWindow.document).documentElement;
elem.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].scrollTop = 300;
```

Notice that it's requesting jsfiddle. Browsers block accessing the DOM of iframes from other domains.

Reference for scrolling cross domain: [Scroll a cross-domain child iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864870/scroll-a-cross-domain-child-iframe)

Comment: What is the double pipe operator?

Comment: That's an or operation. Depending on the browser, the iframe document is  stored in a different place. So doing `seoFrame.contentDocument||seoFrame.contentWindow.document` says "if defined use .contentDocument OR use .contentWindow.document"